# trig help? word problem finding how far a piece of gum travels. work included

Tags: trigonometry

There is a piece of gum stuck to Jamie's bicycle tire. If the tire has a diameter of 30 inches, how far does the piece of gum travel in 48° of rotation?

- Rev = 48/360 = 1/15

(1/15) Pi 30

2 PI

right?

-that is not an option though, what am i doing wrong?

a)2n
b)4n
c)4 pi/15
d) pi/15

Answer (score 1):

hint: 48/360 = 2/15

everything else looks fine